# Remove an item if it appears more than 10times and store the new one

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I want to store users 10 previous passwords so that He/she do not use old passwords. For this I have created a table with 3 columns:

- `id`
- `password`
- `userId`

Now if person forgot his password 11th time and do update password then it should remove its 1st old password and hence store new one. What would be the sql query for that?

I have first checked the `count` of `useridentity` which is working perfectly:

```
SELECT userIdentity, COUNT(userIdentity) FROM passwordhistory;
```

Now if `count >10` then I want to remove the row with minimum id associated with it using.

```
DELETE FROM passwordhistory 
 WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) 
               FROM passwordhistory where userIdentity in
                       (SELECT userIdentity, COUNT(userIdentity) 
                          FROM passwordhistory
                       )
            )
```

But this is incomplete as how to delete `userIdentity` with `count>10`.

PasswordHistory.java

```
package com.tcs.webrtc.model;

 import java.io.Serializable; 
 @Entity
 @Table(name="passwordhistory")
 public class PasswordHistory implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2621325802545502360L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@NotNull    
private String userIdentity;
@NotNull
private String password;
public String getUserIdentity() {
    return userIdentity;
}
public void setUserIdentity(String userIdentity) {
    this.userIdentity = userIdentity;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Java, Here is not a free code writing service. Show efforts and we will help. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: @J.Chomel I have tried . Check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use mysql, you should create a list of the id to delete, then remove them:

### Create the list:

```
Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
String queryToCheckPassword="
SELECT MIN(id) 
       FROM passwordhistory where userIdentity in
               (SELECT userIdentity 
                  FROM passwordhistory 
                 group by userIdentity 
                having COUNT(userIdentity) >10
               )
"; 
List listToDel = session.createSQLQuery(queryToCheckPassword).list();
return listToDel .size()>0?true:false;
```

### Remove by id (this is where the java man comes);

```
<for each item in listToDel >
     delete from passwordhistory where id = :id
```

Comment: Are you capable of creating a list from the SQL query I gave?

Comment: Yes if it runs then I am able to

Comment: Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  String queryToCheckPassword="Here comes your query ";

  List listOfFriends =session.createSQLQuery(queryToCheckPassword).list();

  return listOfFriends.size()>0?true:false;

Comment: I removed the queries which wouldn't work in mysql, sorry.